# Knockout.SimpleGrid and nested objects

Tags: knockout.js

I have an object like this:

```
{
    "ObjectId": 20001,
    "Time": "2008-07-12T23:30:00",
    "NestedObject": {
        "NestedObjectId": 45,
        "ParameterName": "Heart Rate",

    }

}
```

My datamapping for SimpleGrid is simply:

```
 { headerText: "Object Id", rowText: "ObjectId" },
 { headerText: "NestedObject", rowText: "NestedObject.NestedObjectId" },
 { headerText: "Time", rowText: "Time" }
```

It does not bind NestedObject.NestedObjectId.  Does anyone know if I'll have to extend knockout in order to get this functionality?  Or is it built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `function` as the parameter of the `rowText`:

```
{ 
    headerText: "NestedObject", 
    rowText: function (item) { return item.NestedObject.NestedObjectId; } 
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvk18u83/). (The sample were taken from here: [Paged grid](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html))